# CALyer memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, calayer

I found my program has a memory leak problem in the detection of memory, the code is as follows

```
- (CALayer *)layerWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame
         contentGravity:(NSString *)aContentGravity
           cornerRadius:(float)aRadius
            doubleSided:(BOOL)aValue
{
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
*****layer.frame = aFrame;*****
if (aContentGravity) {
    layer.contentsGravity = aContentGravity;
}
layer.cornerRadius = aRadius;
layer.masksToBounds = YES;
layer.doubleSided = NO;
layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottom;

return layer;
 }
```

Asterisk is my program memory location，This is the use of up code：

```
   CALayer *testLayer = [self layerWithFrame: layerRect contentGravity:kCAGravityTop cornerRadius:sublayerCornerRadius doubleSided:NO];
```

Comment: why no man reply my question.Is my question is too simple？